# What determines what the newline character(s) of an OS is?

Tags: operating-system, newline

What determines what newline character(s) is used in an operating system? Is it simply a convention/recommended-practice, or is it actually enforced or encouraged in some systemic way, for instance by the availability of a system variable that holds this character?

---

- I don't care *what* the newline character in each OS is; this can be easily googled.
- I am not intersted in the *history* leading to the adoption of a certain character as the newline in a given OS; this is interesting but should be the subject of a different question.

What I'm interested in is what does it even mean to say that a certain OS has adopted a certain character as the newline, how can we tell, and in what way is this choice implemented and supported in the OS.

Comment: Though it might not fully answer your question, there is a good read on this topic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline ... there is at least some historical background differences between Windows and Unix, as well as other systems.

Comment: @PaulT.: This doesn't answer my question one bit.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. However, from that reference, and loosely based on your question, relative to usage in the operating system: 1. **On Unix platforms, where C originated, the native newline sequence is ASCII LF (0x0A), so '\n' was simply defined to be that value**. ... 2. **MS-DOS (1981) adopted CP/M's CR+LF in order to be compatible, and this convention was inherited by Microsoft's later Windows operating system**.  ... Perhaps someone else will respond with something closer to what you seek.